# Visual Studio проект на CUDA runtime: символы юникода в пути сборки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Я создал проект на CUDA через visual studio. Располагается он по пути, содержащем русские символы. При сборке проекта, возникает ошибка:
`Error C1083 Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\Iieuciaaoaeu\source\repos\CudaRuntimeTest\CudaRuntimeTest\x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj': No such file or directory`
Как вы понимаете, папки **Iieuciaaoaeu** не существует, это ошибка кодирования русского текста. Я изменил параметр **Configuration properties -> Advanced -> Character set** на **Use Unicode Character Set** в свойствах проекта, но это не помогло. Где-то же должен быть параметр, позволяющий сборщику использовать другую кодировку?

Comment: Вообще в идеале было бы правильней сменить имя пользователя на латинские символы. Потому что вы еще не только в Visual Studio подобную ошибку словите.

Comment: @AlexZel Я так и поступлю, если не удастся решить проблему. Что мне еще остается делать

Comment: переименовывать пользователя необязательно. достаточно, чтобы он находился «по пути, **не** содержащем русские символы»

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил параметр **/utf8** в **Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options**